# How to position Dot Indicators to be at the bottom of the image slider?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager

I created a image slider using ViewPager and also added dot indicators to make the slider more interactive. However the dot indicators are below the images and I want the dot indicators to be on bottom overlapping the images.

My code is given below and I used the layout:weight element in layouts so the height of images changes according to the screen size.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context="com.example.navigationdrawerfragments.aboutSLFragment">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="4.5">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5.3">

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Current Result
[image: Current Result]

Expected Result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context="com.example.navigationdrawerfragments.aboutSLFragment">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="4.5">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5.3">

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most **optimized** XML layout for your case

You should use relative layout and can modify your XML like this, you can avoid using weights. As weight won't work with relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_main"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout for this kind of view .You can overlap the slider dot over images .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/activity_main"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</FrameLayout>
```